# How to upload custom file (.txt, .rar, .xml, .zip) in php (wordpress)?

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload

I want to enable uploading files directly to the root. Supported file extensions should be: .txt, .rar, .xml, .zip. I'm trying to do this with the code from w3schools, as I'm beginner in php and wordpress plugin development. Plugin works, there is a menu icon on the left admin bar, there is an upload option on the admin page, but when I "upload" the file, there is no file in uploads folder (I'm first trying to do just like the code is on w3schools. The code is:

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
<h2>Test file upload page</h2>
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Select image to upload:
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
</div>
```

and the **PHP** file (upload.php)

```
<?php 
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
} else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != 
"jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been 
uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
}
?>
```

I know that this is not a good approach, and that there are Wordpress functions to to what I'm trying to do, but I just wanted to try this that way... If you know any better way, I would appreciate if you open my eyes. Also, I have another question: Can file upload work on local? I mean, I'm doing everything on localhost with MAMP, and this is for practice purposes.

I haven't edited any of the code to support file extensions I nedded, because I first wanted to test if it works with image files, but it isn't.

EDIT 1:

I also saw that in php.ini file file_uploads directive should be set to On:

```
file_uploads = On
```

But, there is no php.ini file in wordpress directory. Is there a way to edit php.ini file with wordpress plugin? Maybe that is the problem. Just guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following issues with your code:

1. The `upload.php` file is not needed, everything should go in a single file, your main plugin file in this case.
2. As there's no `upload.php` file, the form action should be empty.
3. Everything in your PHP code should be inside `if(isset($_POST["submit"])) { }`, because if nothing was submitted you don't need to execute anything from the upload script.
4. Your `$target_dir` should be an [absolute path](https://serverfault.com/questions/314305/how-to-get-absolute-path-to-website), something like:

   - `/home/user/public_html/wp-content/`
   - `/Users/username/Sites/wp/wp-admin`

Here's a small working example based on the code you posted, I'm using [`wp_upload_dir`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47970/wp-upload-dir-how-to-get-just-the-directory-name) to set the destination directory. In my test, images were uploaded to `http://localhost/wp-content/2018/10/image.png`.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: (SO) Testing upload
 */
add_action('admin_menu', function () {
    add_menu_page( 
        'Upload', 
        'Upload', 
        'read', 
        'so_upload', 
        'so_upload_callback', 
        null, 
        6 // position, just after Posts
    );
});

function so_upload_callback() 
{
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
    <h2>Test file upload page</h2>
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
    </form>
    </div>
    <?php
    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $target_dir = wp_upload_dir();
        $target_file = $target_dir['path'] . '/' . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
        $uploadOk = 1;
        $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
        if($check !== false) {
            echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
            $uploadOk = 1;
        } else {
            echo "File is not an image.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        // Check if file already exists
        if (file_exists($target_file)) {
            echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        // Check file size
        if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
            echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        // Allow certain file formats
        if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != 
            "jpeg"
        && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
            echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
        if ($uploadOk == 0) {
            echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
            // if everything is ok, try to upload file
        } else {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
                echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been 
                    uploaded.";
            } else {
                echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Note that files uploaded this way don't show up on WP media library. Also, if the code is for real, the form needs a nonce field for security (`wp_nonce_field`).

Comment: Wow. Thank you. Can it be done in a way so files uploaded would be on the root of the website (along with wp-content, wp-admin, etc...). Also, can I add another menu page that will be shown as, for example (Uploaded files) and then that page is shown only if there are files that are uploaded, so from there I can delete files? I'm not aksing you to do that for me, but to give me some advices and where should I look. Thanks again for answering my question in such a great and useful way.

Comment: Yes, check the link about "absolute path" that you'll find how to upload wherever you want. Sure, just use `add_submenu_page()` to create a page where you will list the contents of the target directory with images. On Google, use "what you want site:stackoverflow.com" and you'll find lots of code ready to use. Check the advanced search features here on [so] and at [wordpress.se] to find stuff too. Good luck!

Comment: If someone have similar problem, and want the upload destination to the root, you can use: `get_home_path()` instead of `wp_upload_dir()`, and then change change this line `$target_file = $target_dir['path'] . '/' . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);` to `$target_file = get_home_path() . '/' . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);`